# Is it possible to return the child element of a parent element click function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to have a click function for the entire `<tr>`, but when I click on it, I want to return the child element of where my mouse clicked. I know I can just do a `<td>` function, but is it possible to achieve this without specifying the child element with the function?

HTML

```
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
<tr>
```

JS/Jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function () {
 return child clicked element.text;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like `e.target` where `e` is the event:

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

You can try `console.log(e)` then you can see a lot of information for the element that you have clicked on.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get parents and child nodes of the elements you clicked using dom traversal technique in javascript.

`document.getElementById('tr').addEventListener('click',(e)=> console.log(e.target.childNodes) )`

You can execute the code and check your console and work as you wish.